# How do I get my AOC 34" Monitor to a refresh rate of 144Hz instead of 30Hz?

Tags: monitor

I just got this monitor and by running xrandr I can see that it only supports 30Hz at a 3440x1440 resolution. I'd like for it to be running at 144Hz. How do I do this? I'm using the HDMI cable that was provided to me. I've read that I need to use a display port? Is there anything else? I'm kinda lost here. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Version of Ubuntu: Ubuntu 20.04.4
Hardware: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz, GPU: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]

Laptop model and make: ThinkPad X1C 5th W10DG

Comment: Display refresh rates depend highly on the video hardware and the port. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the hardware specifications of your system (2) the brand & model of the hardware. With this, it may be possible to confirm whether the hardware is capable of 144Hz at 1440p.

Comment: Yes, you probably need to use display port. Most HDMI cables and ports do not support the bandwidth required above 1920x1080p @ 60Hz

Comment: @matigo I've gone ahead and edited my post to include the things you asked for. Lemme know if I'm missing anything

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI port on your laptop supports HDMI 1.4b, which isn't capable of doing anywhere near 144 Hz on your monitor. You can probably get 60Hz or maybe 75Hz using a Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J6DT070) (not a recommendation, just an example).The actual refresh rate you will be able to get may vary, because the [spec sheet](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_5th_Gen/ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_5th_Gen_Spec.PDF) does not actually say anything about it.